# Extension realurl - display of SQL query parts in URL

Tags: nginx, typo3, typo3-8.x, realurl

First of all, I have to deal with a project-related upgrade of a TYPO3 version and am also relatively new to the Nginx web server.

I have upgraded a TYPO3 installation from version 7.6-LTS to 8.7-LTS and transferred the site from an IIS (Windows) server to an Ubuntu 18.04 system with Nginx.

I have now discovered the following: the first click on an internal link on the website in the menu e.g. `domain.com/prices` works correctly. The URL `domain.com/prices` is called and also shown in the URL. Now when the page has been reloaded, the same menu item link now looks like this...

```
domain.com/index.php?id=8&L=1%20or%20%281%2C2%29%3D%28select%2Afrom%28select%20name_const%28CHAR%28111%2C108%2C111%2C108%2C111%2C115%2C104%2C101%2C114%29%2C1%29%2Cname_const%28CHAR%28111%2C108%2C111%2C108%2C111%2C108%2C111%2C115%2C104%2C101%2C114%29%2C1%29%29a%29%20- -%20and%201%3D1
```

...instead of the usual `domain.com/prices`. The oontent of the page is still correctly, so the correct page is being loaded.

The Typo3 installation uses the extension `real url`, which is exactly for this feature. It translates `domain.com/index.php?id=8&L=1...` into a speaking url like `domain.com/prices`. So why is it working on the first load, but then no longer?

I also thought, it could be an issue with the configuration of Nginx, but now I think it is a different topic here, because if it is a webserver issue, it won't work the first time, will it?

What can cause this behaviour?

### Update

I actually saw, that the English version of the website is working well. So here, the links are displayed correctly: `domain.com/prices`, `domain.com/modules` and not even not first page load.

Maybe it is helpful. This is the Nginx config, I currently use:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /var/www/domain.com/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/domain.com/ssl/domain.com-2020.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/domain.com/ssl/domain.com-2020.rsa;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Special root site case. prevent "try_files $uri/" + "index" from skipping the cache
    # by accessing /index.php directly
    location =/ {
        recursive_error_pages on;
        error_page 405 = @sfc;
        return 405;
    }

    location @t3frontend {
        # Using try_files for ease of configuration demonstration here,
        # you can also fastcgi_pass directly to php here
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location @sfc {
        # Perform an internal redirect to TYPO3 if any of the required
        # conditions for StaticFileCache don't match
        error_page 405 = @t3frontend;

        # Query String needs to be empty
        if ($args != '') {
            return 405;
        }

        # We can't serve static files for logged-in BE/FE users
        if ($cookie_staticfilecache = 'fe_typo_user_logged_in') {
            return 405;
        }
        if ($cookie_be_typo_user != '') {
            return 405;
        }

        # Ensure we redirect to TYPO3 for non GET/HEAD requests
        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
            return 405;
        }

        charset utf-8;
        try_files /typo3temp/tx_staticfilecache/${scheme}/${host}/${server_port}${uri}/index.html
        /typo3temp/tx_staticfilecache/${scheme}/${host}/${server_port}${uri}
        =405;
    }

    location /typo3temp/tx_staticfilecache {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    # Prevent clients from accessing hidden files (starting with a dot)
    # This is particularly important if you store .htpasswd files in the site hierarchy
    # Access to `/.well-known/` is allowed.
    # https://www.mnot.net/blog/2010/04/07/well-known
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    location ~* /\.(?!well-known\/) {
        deny all;
    }

    # Prevent clients from accessing to backup/config/source files
        location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|conf|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to composer files
    location ~* composer\.(?:json|lock) {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to flexform files
    location ~* flexform[^.]*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to language files
    location ~* locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to static typoscript files
    location ~* ext_conf_template\.txt|ext_typoscript_constants\.(?:txt|typoscript)|ext_typoscript_setup\.(?:txt|typoscript) {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to miscellaneous protected files
    location ~* /.*\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to recycler and temporary directories
    location ~ _(?:recycler|temp)_/ {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to configuration files stored in fileadmin
    location ~ fileadmin/(?:templates)/.*\.(?:txt|ts|typoscript)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to libaries, source and temporary compiled data
    location ~ ^(?:vendor|typo3_src|typo3temp/var) {
        deny all;
    }

    # TYPO3 - Block access to protected extension directories
    location ~ (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?|Documentation|docs?)/ {
        deny all;
    }
}
server {
    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com;
    return 404; 
}
```

And this is the config of `realurl`:

[image]

[image]

The template analysis does not show any error. This is the template analysis for `realurl`:

[image]

### Update 2

I'm a step further in this issue. I've read the bug report https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/333 which is similar to my issue. I tried to switch the `config.linkVars` value from `L` to `L(0,1)`. That helped in the URL issue. But now it switches always back to German language.

With the setting `L` in `config.linkVars`, it added the language in the url, if it was not German:

`domain.com/en/prices`

With the new value `L(0,1)` it removes the language in the URL

`domain.com/prices`

So it always shows the German version of the page. I even tried to set the value to `L(0,2)`, because of German, English and French language is integrated (1=English, 2=French), but it does not help in this case. It switches always back to German because of the missing language code in the URL.

Comment: First I would check why there is a part of an sql query is added after the language parameter (&L=1). Maybe there is something wrong with your typoscript. Maybe then the links are working correct.

Comment: @RenéPflamm, thanks for your answer. Can you tell me where I can check this?

Comment: look at the typoscript object browser under template, switch to typoscript if constants are shown, search for `name_const` or something else from the query. Maybe an template analys (also under template) shows some failures.

Alternative show at the place where you defined the L param in your typoscript and look if some braces are missing.

Comment: I've added the configs from `realurl`. In the constants of typoscript object browser there is no entry from `realurl`.

Comment: @RenéPflamm I'm a step forward. I found this bug report, which explains my issue. https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/333 I've changed the `config.linkVars` value from `L` to `L(0,1)`, thatt helped in the URL issue, but now it switches always back to German language. Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: See also detailed information in my UPDATE 2 section

Comment: Please don't render software names (Ubuntu, Nginx, etc) as code here. They are proper nouns, so just require the observation of correct case rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Now I found the solution.
As I wrote in the comments it was the config setting:

```
config.linkVars
```

which was set initially to

```
config.linkVars = L
```

After I found this bug report

https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/333

I saw that I need to limit the `L`-value for security reasons.
In our case 0 for german, 1 for english, 2 for french:

```
config.linkVars = L(0-2)
```

Then all worked fine.